# Import Excel in Yii2

Tags: mysql, excel, import, yii2-advanced-app

I have yii2 application using advanced template and database mySql, i already make function for import an excel file to one of the table,
I made the function in a controller named student that contains CRUD of students data.this is my code

```
 public function actionImportExcel()
{
    $inputFile = 'uploads/siswa_file.xlsx';
    try{
        $inputFileType = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFile);
        $objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFile);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die('Error');
    }

    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
    $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
    $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

    for($row=1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++)
    {
        $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A'.$row.':'.$highestColumn.$row,NULL,TRUE,FALSE);

        if($row==1)
        {
            continue;
        }

        $siswa = new Siswa();
        $siswa->nis = $rowData[0][0]; 
        $siswa->nama_siswa  = $rowData[0][1]; 
        $siswa->jenis_kelamin  = $rowData[0][2]; 
        $siswa->ttl  = $rowData[0][3]; 
        $siswa->alamat  = $rowData[0][4]; 
        $siswa->telp  = $rowData[0][5]; 
        $siswa->agama  = $rowData[0][6]; 
        $siswa->nama_ortu  = $rowData[0][7]; 
        $siswa->telp_ortu  = $rowData[0][8]; 
        $siswa->pekerjaan_ortu = $rowData[0][9];
        $siswa->tahun_masuk = $rowData[0][10];
        $siswa->kelas = $rowData[0][11];
        $siswa->save();

        print_r($siswa->getErrors());
    }
    die('okay');
}
```

but i don't know how to make a button in a view to make this function work. i mean i want to make a button that when the user click the button and browse their excel file they can import that file and the data inside the excel can import to database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should upload the file

and then processing with your function

there are several parts of code you must produce ..

eg a view for the user to upload the file

> **View: @app/views/site/upload.php**
>
> ```
> <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>
>
>     <?= $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
>
>     <?= $form->field($model, 'imageFile')->fileInput() ?>
>
>     <button>Submit</button>
>
> <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
> ```
>
> **Controller: @app/controllers/SiteController.php**
>
> ```
> namespace app\controllers;
>
> use Yii;
> use yii\web\Controller;
> use app\models\UploadForm;
> use yii\web\UploadedFile;
>
> class SiteController extends Controller
> {
>     public function actionUpload()
>     {
>         $model = new UploadForm();
>
>         if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
>             $model->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFile');
>             if ($model->upload()) {
>                 // file is uploaded successfully
>                 return;
>             }
>         }
>
>         return $this->render('upload', ['model' => $model]);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> **Model: @app/models/UploadForm.php**
>
> ```
> namespace app\models;
>
> use yii\base\Model;
> use yii\web\UploadedFile;
>
> class UploadForm extends Model
> {
>     /**
>      * @var UploadedFile
>      */
>     public $imageFile;
>
>     public function rules()
>     {
>         return [
>             [['imageFile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
>         ];
>     }
>
>     public function upload()
>     {
>         if ($this->validate()) {
>             $this->imageFile->saveAs('uploads/' . $this->imageFile->baseName . '.' . $this->imageFile->extension);
>             return true;
>         } else {
>             return false;
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

the code is from [this doc](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/input-file-upload.md)

Comment: i already use your answer but there is an error,i use your view code in my _form.php then model and controller in model and controller,then there is still an error said unknown property' ::imageFile.How can fix this?